# Are questions about a game universe's lore on topic on the gaming stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I've asked a couple questions so far about lore or backstories, and have received mixed feedback. I have read the FAQ and I would think it sort of fits in with "Plot and characters in games", but it's not explicit. Lore questions are also not explicitly forbidden.

So, are these questions on topic or not?

Here are the relevant questions I've asked:

[Are Terran units cloned? Where do they come from?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242658/are-terran-units-cloned-where-do-they-come-from)

[Was Diablo 2 inspired by real locations? (10k)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232754/was-diablo-2-inspired-by-real-locations)

Comment: Long story short: Yes they're on topic, but there is a vocal minority who dislikes them and continues to downvote/closevote against them in this way. There are a few discussions here on meta where this was hashed out, but I am not in a position at the moment to be able to find them

Comment: @galacticninja Thanks for finding those. So why don't we update the FAQ since people (even moderators) are clearly still confused about this?

Comment: Related (reposting as previous comment has been deleted): 
[Should lore questions as an entire category be banned?](//meta.arqade.com/q/7696/4797),
[When is it appropriate to close a lore question as "not addressed directly through in-universe sources"?](//meta.arqade.com/q/7673/4797), 
[Is "This question requires developer only knowledge" the same thing as developer intent?](//meta.arqade.com/q/9901/4797), 
[Do we close plot-explanation questions if the answer is 'there is no explanation'?](//meta.arqade.com/q/8473/4797)